# Spring data JPA save all or none and exception rollback

Tags: java, transactions, spring-data-jpa

Nested call of JpaRepository.save(), the requirement is to save all or none.

DAOs are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A implements Serializable{
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B implements Serializable{
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
public class C implements Serializable{
}
```

Repositories are :

```
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, String> {
}

public interface BRepository extends JpaRepository<B, String> {
}

public interface CRepository extends JpaRepository<C, String> {
}
```

Let's say DAOService layer have methods as depicted below:

```
persistA(){
   persistB(b)
   aRepository.save(a);
}

persistB(B b){
   bRepository.save(b);
}

persistC(C b){
   cRepository.save(c);
}

persistAll(){
    persistA(a);
    persistC(c);
}
```

Here the requirement is all the database objects(**A, B, and C**) to be saved as part of same transaction only which should be new. In case of exception(**checked exception, as runtime exception already rollback everything**) during the save of any of the object, nothing should be save. Meaning either everything saved to DB or nothing is saved.

Per the information shared in the below links:

1. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ts1/index.html
2. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation

I have implemented this the following way:

```
@Transactional(propagation  = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
persistAll(){

}

@Transactional(propagation  = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
persistA(){
}

@Transactional(propagation  = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
persistB(B b){
}

@Transactional(propagation  = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
persistC(C c){
}
```

Is there a way to check if the same transaction is being used for saving A, B, as well as C.

Also, I would like to know if the following code snippet

```
@Transactional(propagation  = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
persistAll(){

}

@Transactional(propagation  = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
persistA(){
}

@Transactional(propagation  = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
persistB(B b){
}

@Transactional(propagation  = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
persistC(C c){
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
@Transactional(propagation  = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
persistAll(){

}


persistA(){
}

persistB(B b){
}


persistC(C c){
}
```

Comment: It's in the same transaction by definition. Why do you want to check this?

Comment: As you said "It's in the same transaction by definition", I just want to confirm this. So, want to know if this can be checked. @SimonMartinelli

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a transaction id or something similar. But you could check if Spring Transaction started a new transaction:

```
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().isNewTransaction();
```

So in `persistAll()` this should return true and in all other methods false.

Comment: I had this tried already per the suggestion in one of the threads I was going through. I run into this error: org.springframework.transaction.NoTransactionException: No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope. I even tried using TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() but no luck. Not getting any information.

Comment: I have a spring boot application. While application runs I have exposed a rest end point to trigger the database insert/save operation.

Comment: And where you call the TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().isNewTransaction(); you are in a method that has a @Transactional annotatoin?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot or Spring? And if only Spring how do you configure the TransactionManager?

Comment: Using spring boot.